# how to get listview item on button click and save to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listviewitem

I've four textviews and a button in listview. when user clicks on the button i want to get the value of these four textviews and pass to the database. I'm confuse how to save the data of selected item to sqlite.

```
public class PlannningListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    public ArrayList<Planning> planArraylist;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public Activity planActivity;

    public PlannningListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<Planning> planArraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.planArraylist = planArraylist;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return planArraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_lv_item, null);
        }

        Planning p = planArraylist.get(position);

        TextView tvDocCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Plan_no);
        TextView tvDocName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doc_name);
        TextView tvmon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mon);
        TextView tvAdr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adr);
        Button   btn_save =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);


        tvDocCode.setText(p.getDocCode());
        tvDocName.setText(p.getDocName());
        tvmon.setText(p.getTerrCode());
        tvAdr.setText(p.getAdr());
        return convertView;
    }
    private OnClickListener ButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
           // Log.v(TAG, "item clicked, row %d", position);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I can't see any code where you are trying to save the data into DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTag()`and `getTag()` method on  your button.

Please look at the code below:

You have to change getItem method:

```
@Override
public Planning getItem(int arg0) {
    return planArraylist.get(arg0);
}
```

Update your getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    Button   btn_save =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_save.setTag(position);

    ...
}


private OnClickListener ButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = (int)v.getTag();
        Planning planning = getItem(position);
        yourDatabaseHelper. getRuntimeExceptionDao(Planning.class).createOrUpdate(planning);
    }
};
```

One more thing. You should implement `ViewHolder` please read about this pattern, and the best solution for you is use `RecyclerView`, getting position is already implemented there in `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

Comment: Thanks so much. could you please show me how can i pass value to database

Comment: Do you use some library to write it to Db or  just DatabaseHelper?

Comment: i'm using databasehelper and i know the method of insertion, but i'm not getting how to get text values using position

Comment: Which text values do you mean? I thing that you want to insert your object.

Comment: If you want to get values from Planning object. You have to get it from array by getItem position method as in my post and inset it to db

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. Thanks.

Comment: konrad i've not tested it yet in my project. can i ask you if i face any problem?

Comment: Create gist with your code https://gist.github.com/ or public your problem on stack in different topic and give me link I will help you

Comment: And ping me by comment on comment

Comment: i asked a question here. please see and thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382479/set-progress-dialog-in-base-adapter

Comment: Hi I saw that someone helped you :) do you need more help?

Comment: Konrad those answers did not solve my problem, i'm getting the same old exception if you could see it otherwise no problem.

Comment: Could you attach your log?

Comment: i've readded log.  please check on this link.                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382479/set-the-progress-dialog-in-base-adapter

Comment: The problem is not with db saving. It is with the display dialog - so lets go to next your topic. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382479/set-the-progress-dialog-in-base-adapter

Comment: hi konrad. dear i have a ques could you please take a look to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553967/splash-screen-get-stuck-and-never-get-passed

Comment: Konrad please take a look at this question, I'm not getting any solution         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108269/android-count-and-delete-rows-from-sqlite?noredirect=1#comment50232251_31108269

Comment: Konrad sorry for disturbing you I'm not getting any response. I would appreciate if you look into my problem at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129835/how-to-get-time-from-network-in-android?noredirect=1#comment50271678_31129835

Comment: @Anita I saw that someone helped you. Is this solution right to you?

Comment: hi Konrad. dear I have a task, please advice me how to achieve it                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414398/how-to-get-the-content-of-listview-with-a-button-outside-the-list/31415932#31415932

Comment: hi Konrad, hope you are doing great. sorry for disturbing you but I've a serious problem and i did not get any response on stack, i would be really great full if you see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687463/android-app-sends-duplicate-records-to-server-through-restful-webservice?noredirect=1#comment53219487_32687463

Comment: dear i'm waiting please let me know if you could help me.

Comment: @Andrain I am sorry but I am very busy now. I can promise nothing to you. I am sorry

Comment: Its ok Konrad, you can see when you get free time, I can wait. I'am facing this problem from a month but I did not get the root cause,you are the only one experienced person I know..