# Android: Count and delete rows from sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to delete some records from my database tables, for example **table A** and **table B**. Both **table A** and **table B** has a column name `sycn_status`. I want to delete only those records where the value of `sync_status` is **C**. For this purpose I wrote the following method but I'm getting the exception.

```
public void RemoveSyncData(){

    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
    //db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE +" WHERE KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS ='C'");
    db.close();
```

Here I'm only checking for one table. and the second thing I want to count the deleting records so that users should know how much data is deleted.

Logcat errors

```
06-29 05:02:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 05:02:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:   KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM dailyattendance WHERE KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS ='C'
06-29 05:02:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-29 05:02:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
06-29 05:02:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
```

Database method for deleting records.
i'm calling the delete method from the button click

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") public void CleanAppDataClick(View V) {

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Others.this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Cleaning");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");//
    Log.e("button delete data", "clicked");           
    usersqlite_obj.open();
    usersqlite_obj.RemoveSyncData();     
    dismissLoadingDialog();
}
```

Here is the method in database class.

```
public boolean RemoveSyncData(){

    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE +" WHERE "+KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS +"='C'");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DCR +" WHERE "+KEY_DCR_SYN_STATUS +"='C'");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DCRNV +" WHERE "+KEY_DCRNV_SYN_STATUS +"='C'");


    db.close();
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Make sure that  KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS present  in that table?

Comment: Can you post table structure related to this question ?

Comment: if i am not wrong you wanted to write like this `"DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE +" WHERE "+KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS "+"='C'"`

Comment: sorry my mistake added extra double quote there.. use this `"DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE +" WHERE "+KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS +"='C'"`

Comment: @bharat now i'm getting the null pointer exception

Comment: at which line... and make sure variable `db` and `context` is not null.

Comment: After you modified the table, you have to uninstall and reinstall the app. OR use the `onUpgrade()` feature, which requires the increase of the  `DATABASE_VERSION` constant.

Comment: The correct SQL for deleting: `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " +  DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE + " WHERE " + KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS + " = 'C'");`

Comment: @Anita As I see your issue is resolved. Is that right?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Thanks for replying. It is half solved. I also want to count the rows  before deleting. could you please show me the code.

Comment: @Anita How execSQL method looking? Basically when you call   sqLiteDatabase.delete(...) method , it returns number of deleted rows.

Comment: You can retrieve the count before deleting by using `db.rawQuery("SELECT Count(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE + " WHERE " + KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS + " = 'C'");`. Or use `int rows = db.delete(...);`, as suggested by @KonradKrakowiak

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak I have added the method for deleting records please check my post.

Comment: @Anita Use `db.delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) `instead of  `execSQL(String sql)` and you will get number of removed items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE +" WHERE "+KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS ='C');
```

UPDATE:

As requested in one of the comments, the problem was with statement which is executed.

```
"DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE +" WHERE KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS ='C'"
```

In the above statement SQLite will not be able to recognize the string as valid.

DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE is a string value which does not require double quotes around it.

KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS was included within double quotes, but its already a string value, so moving it out of double quotes.

'C'" String was ending here, since the quote ended before keyword KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS removing the last occurance of double quotes.

Comment: this whole line is giving an error, please check again its syntax.

Comment: Remove last occurrence of inverted comma. Check updated answer.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception, you made a typo in your field declaration that

```
KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS = "KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS".
```

Change it to

```
KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS = "sync_status";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
public void RemoveSyncData(){

    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
    //db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE +" WHERE sync_status ='C'");
    db.close();
```

I hope above code will work for you.