# How to get current Time irrespective of the device or system time?

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to get actual time in my android application instead of getting what the system/device returned.

Suppose today is date 3 dec and I have changed my system date to 4 dec, now I will get the date 4 dec in my application which is not correct.

I have applied following code:

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()
c.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
val sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND)
val mYear1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val mMonth1 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val mDay1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

to get the time. But this only returned the device/system date.

All I want is to get the actual date. (i.e.. **3 dec** in my case not **4 dec**).

I also tried to get the time from GPS, but this only returns the time from the last known location, which can get me trouble.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java/6697884#6697884 see this.

Comment: @PrashantSable It will return time from device.

Comment: If you have network access then get it from network: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129835/how-to-get-time-from-network-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get time from Network in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129835/how-to-get-time-from-network-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't trust user settings or device time, you can simply use an API, such as http://worldtimeapi.org/ and get the current time from it in any time zone you like.

Comment: This is a good solution but unfortunately it requires internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a NTP (Network Time Protocol) server if you can't trust your user device time

I found this repository:
https://github.com/AllanHasegawa/Tempo

Comment: how can i use this.. can please post any code of it